# TypeError while retriving prototype properties

Tags: javascript, object, constructor, prototype-programming

I have the following code:

```
function inheritPrototype (sup, sub) {
  var proto = Object.create(sup.prototype);
  Object.defineProperty(proto, "constructor", {value : sub});
  sub.prototype = proto;
}

function Person (name, age) {
  this.name = name;
  this.age = age;

  if (!Person.prototype.getName) {
    Person.prototype.getName = function () { return this.name; }
    Person.prototype.getAge = function () { return this.age; }
  }
}

function Employee (name, age, skills) {
  Person.call(this, name, age);
  this.skills = skills;

  if (!Employee.prototype.getSkills) {
    inheritPrototype(Person, Employee);
    Employee.prototype.getSkills = function () { return this.skills; }
  }
}

var person = new Person ("Dave", 21);
var employee = new Employee ("David", 22, ["C", "C++", "Java", "Python", "PHP"]);

console.log(employee.getSkills());
```

`inheritPrototype` is just defined to prevent the double calling of the parent (`Person`) constructor. To keep things clear, I am assigning prototype properties inside the constructors and to prevent it happening each time a new instance is created, I am checking if a prototype property exists. If it does, then we don't want to reassign properties, otherwise we do. The problem is, I am getting a TypeError saying '`employee.getName is not a function`'. This is only happening when I am trying to access Employee's prototype properties using Employee instances. The person constructor has the same way to assign Prototype properties but it works fine.

```
console.log(person.getName()); // "Dave"
console.log(employee.getSkills()); // or getName or anything, TypeError
```

I guess I am doing something silly there but can't spot it. So, what's wrong?

Comment: Why do you need inheritPrototype method? can you elaborate more on this? "To keep things clear, I am assigning prototype properties inside the constructors and to prevent it happening each time a new instance is created, I am checking if a prototype property exists."

Comment: @Sreekanth I don't want to call the Person constructor twice. If instead I have been doing this `Employee.prototype = new Person ()`, I would have been calling the constructor twice. The pattern I am using is know as `Parasitic Combination Inheritance`.

Comment: Any suggestions guys, Please?

Comment: I need to look into the Parasitic Combination Inheritance before I can make a comment. However, the reason you are seeing the error on Employee but not on Person is due to the call being made to inheritPrototype on Employee.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about calling the `inheritPrototype` outside?

This works for me:

```
function inheritPrototype (sup, sub) {
  var proto = Object.create(sup.prototype);
  Object.defineProperty(proto, "constructor", {value : sub});
  sub.prototype = proto;
}

function Person (name, age) {
  this.name = name;
  this.age = age;

  if (!Person.prototype.getName) {
    Person.prototype.getName = function () { return this.name; }
    Person.prototype.getAge = function () { return this.age; }
  }
}

function Employee (name, age, skills) {
  Person.call(this, name, age);
  this.skills = skills;

  if (!Employee.prototype.getSkills) {
    Employee.prototype.getSkills = function () { return this.skills; }
  }
}

inheritPrototype(Person, Employee); // <= FIX

var person = new Person ("Dave", 21);
var employee = new Employee ("David", 22, ["C", "C++", "Java", "Python", "PHP"]);

console.log(person.getName()); // returns "Dave"
console.log(employee.getSkills()); // returns ["C", "C++", "Java", "Python", "PHP"]
console.log(employee.getName());  // returns David
```

Comment: It works for me too. But I want to know the reason why it does not work when written like that.

Comment: because if you do it inside the `function Employee ()` definition, the inheritance only happens when an Employee is defined.

This means, if you use your original code and do `var employee = new Employee` twice in a row, it works. because the inheritance happens after the first construction.

Comment: If you want it to work inside the `function Employee()`, you might need to inherit the instance and not the function, maybe using `inheritPrototype(Person, this)` but not sure if that works.

Answer (score 0):

Primarily this issue is due to the mismatched prototype reference once inheritPrototype method is invoked.

In the inheritPrototype method, you have Object.create(sup.prototype) which is trying to create a new instance out of the prototype which isn't the same object reference used on creating the Employee Object.

This can be seen in the console logs printed for Employee prototype where a new reference is created for prototype, where as EmployeeOne, which doesn't call the inheritPrototype method has the same reference.

So, the reason why you see an exception is because of the reference mismatch. Even though you are referring the prototype, the references are different before and after the inheritMethod invocation.

I dont have a documentation to back up my theory, however, I believe as the prototype reference has changed in case of inheritPrototype method invocation call, which is the case why the newly added method getSkills is not visible on prototype chain lookup on that object.

However, once the prototype value is updated during the first employee call, subsequent employee objects were able to see the new getSkills, due to fact that prototype reference is now pointing to the prototype reference of the earlier invocation.

```js
function inheritPrototype(sup, sub) {
  var proto = Object.create(sup.prototype);
  Object.defineProperty(proto, "constructor", {
    value: sub
  });
  sub.prototype = proto;
}

function Person(name, age) {
  this.name = name;
  this.age = age;

  if (!Person.prototype.getName) {
    Person.prototype.getName = function () {
      return this.name;
    }
    Person.prototype.getAge = function () {
      return this.age;
    }
  }
}

function Employee(name, age, skills) {
  Person.call(this, name, age);
  this.skills = skills;

  var p = Employee.prototype;
  if (!Employee.prototype.getSkills) {
    inheritPrototype(Person, Employee);

    Employee.prototype.getSkills = function () {
      return this.skills;
    }
  }
  console.log("Employee with inheritPrototype invocation : " + (p === Employee.prototype));
}


function EmployeeOne(name, age, skills) {
  Person.call(this, name, age);
  this.skills = skills;

  var p = EmployeeOne.prototype;
  if (!EmployeeOne.prototype.getSkills) {
    EmployeeOne.prototype.getSkills = function () {
      return this.skills;
    }
  }
  console.log("EmployeeOne without inheritPrototype invocation : " + (p === EmployeeOne.prototype));
}


var person = new Person("Dave", 21);
var employee = new Employee("David", 22, [
  "C",
  "C++",
  "Java",
  "Python",
  "PHP"
]);

var employeeOne = new EmployeeOne("DavidOne", 22, [
  "C",
  "C++",
  "Java",
  "Python",
  "PHP"
]);

var employeeTwo = new Employee("David", 22, [
  "C",
  "C++",
  "Java",
  "Python",
  "PHP"
]);

console.log(employeeTwo.getSkills());
```

I tried to lookup the references on Employee constructor after inheritPrototype method, the explanation I have above on the new reference to the prototype turns out  to be correct.

```js
function inheritPrototype(sup, sub) {
  var proto = Object.create(sup.prototype);
  Object.defineProperty(proto, "constructor", {
    value: sub
  });
  sub.prototype = proto;
}

function Person(name, age) {
  this.name = name;
  this.age = age;

  if (!Person.prototype.getName) {
    Person.prototype.getName = function() {
      return this.name;
    }
    Person.prototype.getAge = function() {
      return this.age;
    }
  }
}

function Employee(name, age, skills) {
  Person.call(this, name, age);
  this.skills = skills;

  var p = Employee.prototype;
  if (!Employee.prototype.getSkills) {
    inheritPrototype(Person, Employee);
    Employee.prototype.getSkills = function() {
      return this.skills;
    }
  } else {
    inheritPrototype(Person, Employee);

  }
  if (employeeTwoPrototype !== undefined) {
    console.log("Employee with 2nd inheritPrototype invocation : " + (p === employeeTwoPrototype));

    console.log("Employee with 2nd inheritPrototype invocation : " + (p === Employee.prototype));
  } else {
    console.log("Employee with inheritPrototype invocation : " + (p === Employee.prototype));
  }
}



function EmployeeOne(name, age, skills) {
  Person.call(this, name, age);
  this.skills = skills;

  var p = EmployeeOne.prototype;
  if (!EmployeeOne.prototype.getSkills) {
    EmployeeOne.prototype.getSkills = function() {
      return this.skills;
    }
  }
  console.log("EmployeeOne without inheritPrototype invocation : " + (p === EmployeeOne.prototype));
}


var person = new Person("Dave", 21);
var employee = new Employee("David", 22, [
  "C",
  "C++",
  "Java",
  "Python",
  "PHP"
]);

var employeeOne = new EmployeeOne("DavidOne", 22, [
  "C",
  "C++",
  "Java",
  "Python",
  "PHP"
]);

var employeeTwo = new Employee("David", 22, [
  "C",
  "C++",
  "Java",
  "Python",
  "PHP"
]);

var employeeTwoPrototype = Employee.prototype;
var employeeThree = new Employee("David", 22, [
  "C",
  "C++",
  "Java",
  "Python",
  "PHP"
]);


console.log(employeeTwo.getSkills());
```